# I am looking for an XSLT usage pattern that will reparent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am pretty skilled at XSLT, but I've not encountered before the need to transform an XML document and implement reparenting. The input XML is in OPML format:

```
<opml>
  <body>
    <outline text="root">
      <outline text="child 1">
        <outline text="some text A">
          <outline text="some text B" />
          <outline text="some text C" />
      ...
      <outline text="child 2">
        <outline text="some text D">
          <outline text="some text E" />
          <outline text="some text F" />
  ....
```

I have another xml doc which is used in the transform, and lists nodes and new parent nodes,
and it has entries such as:

```
<row>
  <node>some text A</node>
  <newParent>child 2</newParent>
</row>
```

Has anyone tackled such programmatic reparenting using XSLT?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that showa a well-formed XML example of the inputs and the expected result. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Posing problems like this is a great way for me and others to learn what XSLT is capable of.  My specific problem turned out to be a bit more complex because what turned out be the case is that the users had edited the test and production xml at the same time - using a graphical editor that I had built for the business. Below is the solution that I came up with. I would be interested to hear if it can be simplified. And also if XSLT 2.0 solution would be more succinct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- 
       Merge/refactor the OPML that is in test. 
       Both test and production were modified and now need to be reconsiled. 
       The input to this transform is the test xml.
  -->

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:param name="imported" />
  <xsl:param name="imported2" />

  <!-- xml from Excel changes sheet -->
  <xsl:variable name="changes" select="document($imported)/table" />

  <!-- production opml body -->
  <xsl:variable name="prod" select="document($imported2)/opml/body" />

  <!-- identity -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- match and recurse on outline nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="outline">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="@name" />
    <!-- row in change doc that has this node as a parent -->
    <xsl:variable name="changeParentRow" select="$changes/row[productInsertionParent = $nodeName and parentProductInNewStuff != 'NULL']" />

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      <!-- if there is a row in changes doc that has this node as a parent -->
      <xsl:if test="$changeParentRow">
        <!--  from change doc, name of node to insert from prod version -->
        <xsl:variable name="changeNodeName" select="$changeParentRow/productToInsert" />
        <!--  node in prod version -->
        <xsl:variable name="changeNodeProd" select="$prod//outline[@name = $changeNodeName]" />
        <!-- if there is such a node in prod, copy it -->
        <xsl:if test="$changeNodeProd">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$changeNodeProd" mode="merge" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline" mode="merge">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="check" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline" mode="check">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="@name" />
    <!-- copy this node if it wasn't already present in test -->
    <xsl:if test="not(/opml//outline[@name=$nodeName])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing (!!) you mean something like this:

**XML**

```
<opml>
  <body>
    <outline text="root">
      <outline text="child 1">
        <outline text="some text A">
          <outline text="some text B"/>
          <outline text="some text C"/>
        </outline>
      </outline>
      <outline text="child 2">
        <outline text="some text D">
          <outline text="some text E"/>
          <outline text="some text F"/>
        </outline>
      </outline>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

**external.xml**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <node>some text A</node>
        <newParent>child 2</newParent>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="reparent" match="row" use="node" />
<xsl:key name="children" match="outline" use="@parent" />

<xsl:template match="/opml">
    <xsl:variable name="outlines">
        <xsl:for-each select="//outline">
            <xsl:variable name="reparent" select="key('reparent', @text, document('path/to/external.xml'))" />
            <outline parent="{if ($reparent) then $reparent/newParent else ../@text}" text="{@text}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <opml>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$outlines/outline[not(string(@parent))]"/>
        </body>
    </opml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outline">
    <outline text="{@text}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', @text)"/>
    </outline>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml>
   <body>
      <outline text="root">
         <outline text="child 1"/>
         <outline text="child 2">
            <outline text="some text A">
               <outline text="some text B"/>
               <outline text="some text C"/>
            </outline>
            <outline text="some text D">
               <outline text="some text E"/>
               <outline text="some text F"/>
            </outline>
         </outline>
      </outline>
   </body>
</opml>
```

---

Note that there is an implied assumption here that the `text` of an `outline` is unique.

---

### Added:

In view of the confusion expressed in the comments below*, here's an explanation of my method:

This transformation takes place in two steps:

- In step one we construct a "flat" list of all outlines, where each
  outline has a `parent` attribute. The default parent is the existing parent, but if the outline is listed in the external document, then the new parent overrides.

  At the end of this step we have an `$outlines` variable containing:

  ```
     <outline parent="" text="root"/>
     <outline parent="root" text="child 1"/>
     <outline parent="child 2" text="some text A"/>
     <outline parent="some text A" text="some text B"/>
     <outline parent="some text A" text="some text C"/>
     <outline parent="root" text="child 2"/>
     <outline parent="child 2" text="some text D"/>
     <outline parent="some text D" text="some text E"/>
     <outline parent="some text D" text="some text F"/>
  ```
- In step two we reconstruct the hierarchy by outputting the
  "progenitor" outlines (outlines with no parent) first, and then
  populating each outline recursively with its children.

It might be worth mentioning that in this method each outline performs exactly one lookup from the external document - and this lookup is performed using a key.

---

(*) These comments, being now deleted, are reproduced here:

[image]

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The result shown in my answer was produced by the code in my answer, so... Perhaps you should spend more time studying it before criticizing.

Comment: `<outline parent="{if ...}" text="{@text}"/>`

Comment: Wow.. an intermediate result document ... Congrats, this is a really complicated solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

While my first tool of choice is invariably XSLT, I might be inclined to tackle this one by transforming the input

```
<row>
  <node>some text A</node>
  <newParent>child 2</newParent>
</row>
```

into XQuery Update statements:

```
let $node := //outline[@text='some text A']
let $newParent := //outline[@text='child 2']
return (
    insert nodes $node into $newParent,
    delete nodes $node
)
```

and then execute the resulting XQuery Update script.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm on .Net, so the equivalent would be Linq for XML - which has similar semantics and could thus do this.  I don't think I'd have to "generate" the Linq - I can just loop over the rows and invoke the appropriate insert delete on each.

Answer (score 1):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**

**As simple as this** (*no variables, no conditionals, no literal-result elements, no intermediate-result document, no `xsl:for-each`*) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kOutlineByText" match="outline" use="@text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kUpdatedNodesByText" match="node" use="."/>
 <xsl:param name="pupdSpec">
    <row>
      <node>some text A</node>
      <newParent>child 2</newParent>
    </row>
 </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#default copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline[@text = $pupdSpec/*/newParent]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kOutlineByText', $pupdSpec/*/node)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline[key('kUpdatedNodesByText', @text, $pupdSpec)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<opml>
  <body>
    <outline text="root">
      <outline text="child 1">
        <outline text="some text A">
          <outline text="some text B"/>
          <outline text="some text C"/>
        </outline>
      </outline>
      <outline text="child 2">
        <outline text="some text D">
          <outline text="some text E"/>
          <outline text="some text F"/>
        </outline>
      </outline>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<opml>
   <body>
      <outline text="root">
         <outline text="child 1"/>
         <outline text="child 2">
            <outline text="some text D">
               <outline text="some text E"/>
               <outline text="some text F"/>
            </outline>
            <outline text="some text A">
               <outline text="some text B"/>
               <outline text="some text C"/>
            </outline>
         </outline>
      </outline>
   </body>
</opml>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kOutlineByText" match="outline" use="@text"/>
 <xsl:param name="pupdSpec">
    <row>
      <node>some text A</node>
      <newParent>child 2</newParent>
    </row>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vupdSpec" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pupdSpec']/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:if test="not(current()/@text = $vupdSpec/node)">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="key('kOutlineByText', $vupdSpec/node)
                             [current()[self::outline and @text = $vupdSpec/newParent]]"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same (above) XML document, the same correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<opml>
   <body>
      <outline text="root">
         <outline text="child 1"/>
         <outline text="child 2">
            <outline text="some text D">
               <outline text="some text E"/>
               <outline text="some text F"/>
            </outline>
            <outline text="some text A">
               <outline text="some text B"/>
               <outline text="some text C"/>
            </outline>
         </outline>
      </outline>
   </body>
</opml>
```

Comment: I see you have 
   xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
but I don't see anything not allowed in 1.0. Or am I missing something?

Comment: For example, XSLT 1.0 does not allow result tree fragments like `$pupdSpec` to be used in expressions.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington, There are at least 3 places in the code that do require XSLT 2.0: 1) Trying to access $pupdSpec not as just a string will result in an XSLT 1.0 RTF  error. A fix for this is to use the `document('')` function, 2)  `key('kUpdatedNodesByText', @text, $pupdSpec)` will raise an error for a `key()` function with a 3rd argument. There is also an workaround for this but it might feel rather unnatural. 3) In XSLT 1.0 the value of the `mode` attribute of `<xsl:template>` can only be a single name/token and not 2 as we have here (`<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#default copy">`)

Comment: @ChrisHarrington, Please see the update to this answer: I added **a pure XSLT 1.0 solution**, just 23 lines :) Hope that now this helps.

Comment: If you use `xsl:copy-of`, you miss cases where one rule reparents descendants of another reparented node.

Comment: *"no variables, no conditionals, no literal-result elements, no intermediate-result document, no `xsl:for-each`"* You're saying this like it's a good thing. That is simply not true. All of these are perfectly legitimate tools in the XSLT toolbox. The only question should be *how* they are being used. Dismissing them outright is counterproductive.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, Yes, and in XSLT 1.0 one can apply templates in a second mode, essentially duplicating the identity rule in that mode -- but that is quite inelegant and not necessary for the solution of this specific problem. Note that in the XSLT 2.0 solution there is no `xsl:copy-of`

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is not: "dismissing them outright", using unnecessarily each of this results in additional complexity that could be avoided. If any of these could be avoided, but they are still present tells us that this code is unnecessarily complicated. This XSLT 1.0 solution is just 23 lines, while your XSLT 2.0 solution is 29 lines.

Comment: And, once again, you're boasting about something that has no importance whatsoever.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Oh, We know well this is of no importance to you!

Comment: @michael.hor257k As is your disregard for readability -- long lines that require horizontal scrolling ...   Eww ...

Comment: I do not intend to argue with you. I am only pointing out these things to warn a less experienced reader who might be misled by your reputation and not realize that you wil say anything, no matter how ridiculous, in an effort to belittle me and aggrandize yourself. I don't know what I have ever done to you, but you've been persecuting me for years, finding imaginary faults in whatever I do. Your latest rant about my lines being too long is a prime example of this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Code readability and decreasing complexity are much more important than trying "to belittle anyone". Most Devs are grateful for such notes and do learn from their errors and don't repeat them. "Does having to scroll horizontally make code less readable?" https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62058/does-having-to-scroll-horizontally-make-code-less-readable, " 8. Limit Line Length" in https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118, eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/max-len

Comment: Some history here clearly ;) For me, I didn't interpret Dimitre's "No X" comment as boasting or dismissing these valid xslt constructs.

Comment: Boy I wish MSFT would some day implement xslt 2.0. But after 20 years of not, I have to assume that it'll never happen.

Answer (score -1):

If the `<row>`s are to be executed consecutively, I suggest you use a transformation that processes one row, like

```xml
<xsl:param name="node"/>
<xsl:param name="newParent"/>
<xsl:template match="outline">
  <xsl:if test="not(@text=$node)">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@text"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="outline"/>
      <xsl:if test="self::outline[@text=$newParent]">
        <xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::outline[@text=$node]">
          <xsl:message terminate="yes">Forbidden cycle</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//outline[@text=$node]"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and use non-XSLT means to loop over the `<row>` list and invoke that transformation once per row.

A "forbidden cycle" would be caused by

```xml
<row>
  <node>child 1</node>
  <newParent>some text A</newParent>
</row>
```

or by

```xml
<row>
  <node>some text A</node>
  <newParent>child 2</newParent>
</row>
<row>
  <node>child 2</node>
  <newParent>some text A</newParent>
</row>
```

If the `<row>`s are not to be executed consecutively, can you specify the rules in more detail?

Comment: XSLT - even XSLT 1.0 - is Turing-complete. There is no need to use "non-XSLT means" to complete a transformation.